# Cant create object from a sub class

Tags: python, class

Have a package with one module. In the module root class and sub classes. I publish the package to our internal pypi repo just fine and can install it without problems. When I instantiate the class I cant access the methods in the sub classes. For easy consumption I would like to have all methods from all sub classes available when creating the object. Reason for sub classes is I want to override one argument. Do a lot of api stuff and need different headers for get/put/post etc.

module.py

```
class Root()
  def __init__(self):
   self.attrib1 = whatever1
   self.attrib2 = whatever2

class Get(Root):
  super().__init__(whatever1, whatever2)
  self.headers = {header1}

  def get(self):
    do_stuff and use header1 and access attrib1&2

class Put(Root):
 super().__init__(whatever1, whatever2)
 self.headers = {header2}

  def put(self):
     do_stuff and use header2 and access attrib1&2
```

Dir. struct.

```
my_pkg
    |_____module.py
          |__ __init__.py

__init__.py
from .module import Root
```

Consuming:

```py
from my_pkg import module as rest
api = rest()
a = api.Get() -> Methos not found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from my_pkg import module as rest` : you import the module (ie. module.py itself), not the classes (Root, Get, Put).

You could do:

```py
from my_pkg import module as rest
rest.Get().get()
```

or

```py
from my_pkg.module import Get as rest
rest().get()
```